# Image not displaying in PHP

Tags: php, image

Here don't know why image is not being displayed in php, I think this line has some problem.

```
echo '<img src="' . $row['pic'] . '">';
```

the full code is like this

```
<?php 
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name, email, branch, batch, position, pic FROM users ");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo '<section>'
      . '<header>'
      . '<h2>' . $row['name'] . '</h2>'
      . '<p><span class="posted">'
      . '<br>'
      . $row['batch']
      . '<br>'
      . $row['branch']
      . '<br>'
      . $row['email']
      . '<br>'
      . 'Profession:'
      . $row['position']
      . '</header>'
      . '</section>'
      . '</div>'
      ;
} 
echo '<img src="' . $row['pic'] . '">';
?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$row['pic']`?

Comment: It is a image stored in some folder like images/one.png

Comment: Format your code with proper indentation, and enable proper error reporting.

Comment: Did you make sure it always has a value and is a correct path to a file? I suspect the path is invalid as it is relative which is a recipe for error.

Comment: @JohnConde: Of course it _does not_ have a value – after you edited the code and added indentation, that should be pretty obvious :-)

Comment: a shot in the dark: what about `echo '<img src="images/'.$row['pic'].'">';`?

Comment: @Lovsingh: Go read what the possible return values of `mysqli_fetch_array` are in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

Your `while(){}` loop will run while `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns arrays with information.

In the last iteration, `mysqli_fetch_array()` will return `NULL` and the loop will stop.

At this point `$row['pic']` is not set. In fact `$row` is no longer an array at all. `$row` is `NULL`.

Comment: Minor correction: Not FALSE, but NULL. (But apart from that, your answer is of course correct.)

Comment: True. It's `mysql_fetch_array()` that returns `FALSE`.